# Spring Scheduler Task - parallel

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I have a question about Spring Scheduling Tasks.

I have a two different methods in my service, which are individually timed via the annotation @Scheduled.

```
@Scheduled (cron = "$ {cronA}")
private void aSchedule () {}

@Scheduled (cron = "$ {cronB}")
private void bSchedule () {}
```

All methods should be execute parallel to each other. Method A should also be fired if method A is currently running in another thread. Methods B should only be executed if method B is not running in any other thread.

I have already read that the scheduler only use thread pool of 1 by default. I can now increase the pool size in the configuration. But how do I make sure that method B is really only executed once at a time? What is the best practice for this? Using Async?

Comment: Maybe [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) is what you are looking for? But I am not sure how Spring likes it if you interfere here. Maybe there's a special Spring annotation for that.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html it may be what you are looking for.